# The calling thread cannot access certain Settings because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm currently making improvements to my application and I'm moving the heavy piece of the application that does a lot of manual work to a different thread via `Task.Run`

```
var myTask = Task.Run(() => test()).ContinueWith((Finish) =>
{...}
```

`test()` is the testing method that will be renamed of course, once this is working.

inside the `test()` function I access `Properties.Settings.Default.A` and that works just fine and few lines below I have an if statement where `Properties.Settings.Default.B` is compared and I end up with:

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

I even tried making that an input parameter and then the input variable also gives the same error.

```
void test()
    {
        timer.Start();

        SRCH_Status.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => SRCH_Status.Content = "Retrieving information . . ."));
        SRCH_Progress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => SRCH_Progress.Content = "Scanning in progress"));

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.A == 0)      
        ....


       if (Properties.Settings.Default.B> 1) //ERROR HERE
        {...}
...}
```

What am I doing wrong here?!

Here is the stackTrace property of the exception:

```
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.ClearValue(DependencyPropertyKey key)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.Clear()
at APP.Main.test() in c:\....\Main.xaml.cs:line 718
at APP.Main.<MENU_Start_Click>b__3() in c:\...\Main.xaml.cs:line 187
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Is your Properties, Settings or Default associated with anything UI, or created in the UI/dispatch thread?

Comment: could you show implementation of `Properties.Settings.Default.B`?

Comment: You probably misidentified the statement that threw the exception.  You need to show us the exception's StackTrace property.

Comment: @StepUp B is integer representation of an enum that's related to a custom dropdown menu.. In dropdown you select 1,2,3, that's stored as Level.One,Two,Three and B contains 1 2 or 3 depending on the use.
On load it loads from settings to the usercontrol. But this same thing is happening with the A setting as well. A and B are used in identical places, just on 2 different instances of a user control.

Comment: @HansPassant I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: Right, nothing to do with Properties.Settings.  You omitted the bad code from your snippet.

Comment: @HansPassant No sir, between A and B are just 3 .Clear() calls on lists. and last one is a UI element... wait a second, could that be the cause?.

Comment: I heard that slap to the forehead from three thousand miles away.

Comment: @HansPassant Hahaha, but yep. this issue is fixed :) You can post an answer if you want. I just replaced element.items.clear() with element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((action) => elements.Items.Clear()); and it worked.